# Searching for square bracket with zipgrep

Tags: bash, cygwin, unzip

I have tried this in Cygwin and git-bash - same result.

With plain grep, a `[` character in the pattern can be escaped with a backslash to indicate a literal `[` character is to be searched for.

But this doesn't work with zipgrep:

```
$ zipgrep '\[HashMap' /c/Users/greerob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/7558d13056c1f98be269fed58ae5a8e76c7616d4/jsr166e-1.1.0-sources.jar
grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=
```

Even escaping it twice doesn't work:

```
$ zipgrep '\\[HashMap' /c/Users/greerob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/7558d13056c1f98be269fed58ae5a8e76c7616d4/jsr166e-1.1.0-sources.jar
grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=
```

And trying to specify that the entire pattern is a fixed string rather than a regular expression doesn't work either:

```
$ zipgrep -F '[HashMap' /c/Users/greerob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/7558d13056c1f98be269fed58ae5a8e76c7616d4/jsr166e-1.1.0-sources.jar
grep: conflicting matchers specified
```

How can I search for a `[` character inside the contents of a zip file?

Comment: `zipgrep` is  a script. Try asking the author as the script may be broken.

Comment: Try to specify it as `[[]` or even triple `\\\[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

```
$ zipgrep '[[]HashMap' /c/Users/greerob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/7558d13056c1f98be269fed58ae5a8e76c7616d4/jsr166e-1.1.0-sources.jar
```

seems to work.